# How to use the Ionic Keyboard plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to import the **cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard** like so:

```
import {Keyboard} from 'cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/www/android';
```

I am trying to use the cordova plugin to prevent the keyboard from closing (and the [ionic-plugin-keyboard is deprecated](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-keyboard).)

```
 import {Keyboard} from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

 export class messages {
   constructor (private keyboard:Keyboard){}
   sendMessage(){
     //send message code 
     this.keyboard.show()
   }
 }
```

How can I correctly import this?

Answer (score 2):

First make sure to get rid of any references to the deprecated ionic-plugin-keyboard as well as @ionic-native/keyboard using this:

```
ionic cordova plugin remove ionic-plugin-keyboard
npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/keyboard
```

Check your package.json and your config.xml to be sure all references are gone, in my case I prefer to delete the node_modules and plugins folder when reinstalling plugins, then run

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard --save
```

To install the [non deprecated plugin](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard), now in any class of your project you can use the plugin like this:

```
import { ViewController, } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var cordova:any;
declare var Keyboard:any;

export class BasePage {

    keyboard: any;

    constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController,) {
        this.keyboard = Keyboard;
    }
```

You have to always declare the var like this

add `declare var Keyboard:any;` after imports.

and use when platform is ready

`platform.ready().then(() => { 
   Keyboard.show();
 });`

Comment: **add declare var Keyboard:any; after imports.**
how can i import it ?

Comment: no need for import. 
import { Platform, AlertController, Nav, Events, ModalController } from "ionic-angular";
import .........
......
declare var Keyboard:any;

Comment: @mustafamohamed, forst make sure that you dont have any reference to the ionic-plugin-keyboard plugin or the npm package, then run ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard --save and then you can use it like this" import ..... declare var Keyboard:any;

export class BasePage {

 keyboard: any;

 constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController,) {
  this.keyboard = Keyboard;
 } just be sure the view is already initialized

Comment: Does anyone have an example of how they set this up? Still having issues getting the isVisiable to respond.

Answer (score 0):

use this.keyboard and no need to import anything.  Call this.keyboard.hide()